# Azure Application settings in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, application-settings

Somebody know how to get the Applications settings in angular?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, one way is to use the [npm package app-configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/app-configuration)

and then you can access the config like this

```
const client = new AppConfigurationClient("<connection string>");

const setting = await client.getConfigurationSetting({
  key: "db"
});
```

Comment: Where i declarate AppConfigurationClient?

Comment: Did you read the information provided in the link?

Comment: @Markus Meyer yes , i did , but i dont know if i have to declarete in the app.module